# Retrieve list of documents from Google Drive

Tags: html, google-drive-api

This is what I wish to do:

1. Retrieve my personal list of videos from google drive.
2. Display the list in a web page.
3. Retrieve a single video url as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331837/recover-video-url-through-google-drive-api-in-order-to-stream-the-video-in-an-ht).
4. After getting the absolute video url, play the video with an html5 player.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331342/access-to-all-files-on-a-users-google-drive) I understand that I cannot do this.

Is this true??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a web app, you can use the [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_google_picker) to show a dialog to your users so that they can pick a file from their Drive.

Comment: Hi Alain, thank you for your reply.
I used Google Picker and now I can see all files. 
After the [code you suggested me](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_google_picker) there's another instruction that says "An application can then fetch the file metadata and download the file content as described in the reference documentation for [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get)".

Following the link, I can see another php code.
I'm really not able to understand what I have to use for the $service variable.

Could you help me?

Comment: Instruction on how to set up and authorize a service object is describe in [Retrieve and Use Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials). You should read the entire page, but the service object is specifically instantiated in the [Instantiate a service object](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials#instantiate_a_service_object) section.