# Go client for Google Drive SDK v2

Tags: go, google-drive-api, google-api-go-client

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Are there Go examples using the `code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2` package. Is there another location for it? or just not released yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not yet released, but you can build the client yourself, if you have the library installed with:

```
go get code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v1
cd $GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client
go run google-api-go-generator/gen.go -api=drive:v2
go install ./drive/v2
```

I will submit a patch right now to get it added.

Comment: thanks ali, I'll switch from useing my simple GETS and tryout the go client. I also ran into this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331342/access-to-all-files-on-a-users-google-drive. But I think I can work around that. I wont be pretty though.

Comment: I updated that answer, the latest Drive API allows requesting a full drive scope. Are you building something cool?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Right now I'm building a simple command line drive sync tool mainly for my linux boxes. So far with all the great changes in sdk 2 I have everything in place. I should have something working this week I'll push it to github when its complete.

Comment: Ali I updated the answer encase someone else needs to working with v2.

Comment: This is now committed to the library.

Answer (score 0):

The package is there but not accessible from that URL:

You can browse the code from

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/source/browse/

and download and install it in you GOPATH

Comment: v1 is there but not v2 ie you can "go get code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v1" but not "code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2" it needs to be generated as ali mentioned.