# Google Drive API for Android - Only Drive.SCOPE_FILE access, need read only

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

So I'm a bit of a novice and I wish to list all the files and folders in Google Drive.

I had downloaded the new SDK, got my app all authorised etc.
I used the samples to pick a folder with an opener, and then display the contents in the Listview.

*BUT* - **NO** files were displayed.  It only displays any sub folders from the selected folder.

So it seems the new SDK only has SCOPE_FILE access, which I gather only allows the app to see files that it has created, or ones that the user selects themselves.

But since I need to be able to list all files and folders in a given folder, then this doesn't work for me at all.

From further reading, it seems I have to use the REST Java API (or something), and that this will allow me to get even read-only access to files and metadata.

Problem is, I have having trouble finding what exactly it is I need in terms of Jar files etc, and where I should put them.

Remember, I'm new to all this.

I'm using Android Studio, so could someone tell me:

- what JAR files I need exactly
- where I should put them (in libs folder?)
- do I need to edit build.gradle to include them?
- any example for authorizing?
- and and example for listing files and folders e.g. in the ROOT folder
- do I need the new SDK at all?

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: I see the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331342/access-to-all-files-on-a-users-google-drive

Comment: Thanks I had read that, as well as several posts.  But I am left confused as to what I need to do.

Comment: anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I am surprised how much the Google API sucks. I am having exactly the same problem which renders the Java API useless. I am not even sure if the JSON API is able to do this. And new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle("New folder").build() to create a folder? What kind of retarded monkey invented this abomination?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same problem.

Comment: i'm a python dev turned java only for a custom application on my android. i'm shocked and appalled at almost everything i see.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, the god-damn Java API does not apparently support the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope which is needed to access all files. I tried this:

```
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

And the result is "Unknown error from Google API" and an exception in logs:

```
06-30 14:11:48.803   3023-29855/? E/ClientConnectionOperation﹕ Handling authorization failure
com.google.android.gms.drive.auth.c: Authorization failed: Unsupported scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.auth.g.a(SourceFile:77)
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.api.g.<init>(SourceFile:226)
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.api.a.k.a(SourceFile:46)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.service.g.run(SourceFile:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`
```

I then tried another scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly Which did not work in a different way:

```
06-30 14:12:25.082   3023-29981/? E/ClientConnectionOperation﹕ Handling authorization failure
com.google.android.gms.drive.auth.c: Authorization failed: No valid Drive authorization scope provided.
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.auth.g.a(SourceFile:87)
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.api.g.<init>(SourceFile:226)
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.api.a.k.a(SourceFile:46)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.service.g.run(SourceFile:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Tried this on Google APIs 7.5.0 and wasted two hours on this retarded API. I believe the Java API can't handle this correctly and we will need to do this with the JSON API.

Edit: I have found this very nice tutorial on how to use another Java API to access Google Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java
Unfortunately, it does not work on Android:

```
   Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found
        at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:190)
        at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:139)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
```

at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.getJavaKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:53)

Alice in Wonderland anyone?

Comment: i feel you bro.